# Select DropDownList item inside of a Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have a repeater that contains a few items and among them there are a DropDownList and a Button.

The goal here is to associate an item from the DDL with the selected repeater row.

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="sharedPlansList" runat="server"
    onitemdatabound="sharedPlansList_ItemDataBound"
    onitemcommand="sharedPlansList_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1>&middot; <%# Eval("ProductName") %></h1>
            <div>
            Associer le domaine : 
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="domainList" />
            <asp:Button ID="associateDomaine" Text="Associer" runat="server"
                CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
            </div>
            <div>
                Domaines : 
                <asp:BulletedList runat="server" ID="sharedPlanDomains" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The problem:

When I click the button I have each time an Invalid Postback or Callback exception ( Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. ). But everything seems really standard without anything really exotic. I do not add anything or controls by javascript either.

I have seen solutions where you could put `<pages enableEventValidation="false" />` in the `web.config` but I am not sure it's a good solution since I want to make sure to keep the asp.net built-in security model.

Does any work-around exist?

Comment: Does that CommandArgument/Name actually works? Because I have something similar and I can't make it work at all! Totally ignores the command argument.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain without testing your code a bit (which I don't have time to do right this second), but can you verify if the dynamic CommandArgument you are assigning to your button is the culprit?  If you take it out, does the error keep getting thrown?

If that's the case, you could try to handle each row in the `OnItemDataBound` handler and call

```
ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("associateDomaine", -->CommandArgHere<--);
```

Comment: It's not linked since the error is since before CommandArgument has been added :/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to replace DropDownList with your own DropDownList. Create a subclass of DropDownList, and use that list on ASPX page. I think the content of your DropDownList is changed on the client side (may be, by Javascript?).